# Roll a collection of die in Array and ArrayList java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, dice

Having a bit of a problem here...

•   I created an array and a separate ArrayList object that can store 10 Die objects.

•   I created Die objects and add them to the array, and then created Die objects and add them to the the ArrayList object.

•    I display all the elements of both the array and ArrayList.

**Now I am trying to do 2 things:**

•   roll each of the Die objects in both the array and ArrayList

•   calculate the total value of each collection by adding up the points in each die, and determine which is greater and display those results

Any thought on how I could implement those 2 things listed above?

**Dice Object**

```
public class Dice {

String name;
int[] values;

        // constructor 
        public Dice(int faces,String name){
            int[] values =new int[faces];
            for (int i=0;i<faces;i++){
                values[i]=i+1;
            }
            this.name=name;
            this.values=values;
        }
}
```

**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final int SIZE = 10;
        Dice[] diceList = new Dice[SIZE];
        ArrayList<Dice> diceList2 = new ArrayList<Dice>();

        //create 10 die

        for (int i=0;i<SIZE;i++){
            String name = "dice"+ Integer.toString(i+1);
            Dice dice = new Dice(6,name);
            diceList2.add(dice);
            System.out.println(dice.name);


        }
        System.out.println();

        for (int i = 0; i<SIZE; i++) {
            String name = "dice"+ Integer.toString(i+1);
            Dice dice = new Dice(6,name);
            diceList[i] = dice;
            System.out.println(dice.name);


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is unclear to me why you would use both an array and an ArrayList. Is this so you can play around with the types / practice using them?

Comment: No just experimenting right now with array and arrayList. Haven't thought about any specific way to use them. It's for practice, as you stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To roll the die I would assume you would use something like Random().

```
public class Dice {
    private String name;
    private int[] values;
    private int rolledValue;
    private java.util.Random random = new java.util.Random();

    // constructor 
    public Dice(int faces,String name){
        int[] values =new int[faces];
        for (int i=0;i<faces;i++){
            values[i]=i+1;
        }
        this.name=name;
        this.values=values;
    }

    public void rollDie() {
        rolledValue = values[random.nextInt(values.length)];
    }

    public int getRolledValue() {
        return rolledValue;
    }
}
```

then looping over the array or ArrayList is trivial: (mind you I'd use only 1 die myself and simply call the same die to roll several times.

```
int total = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < diceList.length; ++i) {
     diceList[i].rollDie();
     total+= diceList[i].getRolledValue();
}

int total2 = 0;
for (Dice die : diceList2) {
    die.rollDie();
    total2 += die.getRolledValue();
}
```

However as I said I'd use the dice class differently:

```
public class Dice {
    private final int[] faces;
    private java.util.Random random = new java.util.Random();
    public Dice(final int[] faces) {
        this.faces = faces;
    }
    public int getNextRoll() {
        return faces[random.nextInt(faces.length)];
    }
}
```

And roll them like:

```
Dice d6 = new Dice(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
Dice d4 = new Dice(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4},
int total1 = 0;
int total2 = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    total1 += d6.getNextRoll();
    total2 += d4.getNextRoll();
}
```

But I admit this doesn't help you play with arrays very much :)

Comment: I see what you did it looks good and after some minor tweak  I was able to get the program to work correctly.